# Port exposed by Docker not reachable

Tags: docker, tcp, port, netstat, jupyterhub

I ran a docker container that exposes port `443`. `docker ps` confirms that it is exposed.

```
~ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
42b17c2a4b75        tmp/tmp             "/usr/bin/tini -- /bi"   57 seconds ago      Up 55 seconds       443/tcp             adoring_austin
```

However, `netstat` doesn't show this port. I cannot reach it from a browser either.

```
~ netstat -lt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

The command that I used the run the container is just [`JupyterHub`](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub).

```
[I 2016-11-22 03:12:11.494 JupyterHub app:643] Writing cookie_secret to /jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[W 2016-11-22 03:12:12.562 JupyterHub app:304]
Generating CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN. Restarting the Hub will require restarting the proxy.
Set CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN env or JupyterHub.proxy_auth_token config to avoid this message.
[W 2016-11-22 03:12:12.655 JupyterHub app:757] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2016-11-22 03:12:12.655 JupyterHub app:758] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2016-11-22 03:12:12.655 JupyterHub app:785] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[I 2016-11-22 03:12:12.671 JupyterHub app:1231] Hub API listening on http://172.17.0.3:8081/hub/
[I 2016-11-22 03:12:12.676 JupyterHub app:968] Starting proxy @ http://*:443/
03:12:12.861 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxying https://*:443 to http://172.17.0.3:8081
03:12:12.864 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:444/api/routes
[I 2016-11-22 03:12:12.883 JupyterHub app:1254] JupyterHub is now running at http://127.0.0.1:443/
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you also include the command you ran to start the container?

Comment: I've added this info to the question.

Answer (score 5):

By default, this Jupyterhub Docker image just exposes the port 8000. You can read [here](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#customize-the-configuration-authentication-and-process-spawning). To use SSL (port 443), you might do some extra steps.

You can check it on port 8000.

Stop and remove your containers

```
docker stop jupyterhub
docker rm jupyterhub
```

Start the jupyterhub with the mapped ports:

```
docker run -d --name jupyterhub -p 443:443 -p 8000:8000 jupyterhub/jupyterhub jupyterhub
```

Check it at http://YOUR_DOCKER_IP:8000/, port 443 is not available.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND             CREATED
STATUS              PORTS                                          NAMES
0a123216ee9f        jupyterhub/jupyterhub   "jupyterhub"        26 seconds ago
Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   jupyterhub
```